# Mysql, don't execute next statement if last insert was duplicate

Tags: mysql

Im trying to see if there is a way for me to migrate a big db with mysql queries only, no php.

```
INSERT INTO company (name) VALUES ('name') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=name; 
SET @companyID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO phone2company (companyID,phoneID) VALUES (@companyID,'3');
INSERT INTO address2company (companyID,address) VALUES (@companyID,'address');
```

name is a unique column, so if i get a duplicate, it returns wrong LAST_INSERT_ID(); and the rest of the queries are executed wrong.

is there any way to put an if statement in mysql? smth like:

```
IF (@companyID <> @last_companyID) {
  insert 1....
  insert 2....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function or stored procedure to do that.  Another option is to use a case statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html